# Testing Exception Return Codes With Flask

Tags: python, flask, python-unittest

I have the following chunk of code

```
class APITests(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        app.config['TESTING'] = True
        self.app = app.test_client()
        app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'kjhk'

    def test_exn(self, query):
        query.all.side_effect = ValueError('test')
        rv = self.app.get('/exn/')
        assert rv.status_code == 400
```

I want to check the return code of `self.app.get('/exn/`). However, I notice that `query.all()` propagates the exception to the test case as opposed to trapping it and returning an error code.

How do I check the return codes for invalid inputs when exceptions are thrown in Flask?

Comment: Can you post the controller code.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to do the following to trap the exception.

```
class APITests(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        app.config['TESTING'] = True
        self.app = app.test_client()
        app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'kjhk'

    def test_exn(self, query):
        query.all.side_effect = ValueError('test')
        with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
            rv = self.app.get('/exn/')
            assert rv.status_code == 400
```

For the assertRaises to work, the function call must be contained within some sort of wrapper to catch the exception.

If it is just ran like you did, it is just executed on its own, the exception is not caught and the test case becomes an error instead.

By wrapping the function call within a “with statement”, the exception is passed back to the “assertRaises” in the clause. The “assertRaises” function can now do the comparison on the exception.

To read up more on this, [check this link](https://ongspxm.gitlab.io/blog/2016/11/assertraises-testing-for-errors-in-unittest/)

Answer (score -1):

You can `assertRaise` the exception from `werkzeug`.

Example:

```
from werkzeug import exceptions
def test_bad_request(self):
    with self.app as c:
        rv = c.get('/exn/',
                   follow_redirects=True)
        self.assertRaises(exceptions.BadRequest)
```